# When will a user get deleted in SO?

Tags: support, user-accounts, account-suspension

Recently one of my colleagues user account has been deleted on SO. She is not regular user and she occasionally  logs in into the system to see questions and understand things around, she occasionally answers them and has some rep too(she don't remember the rep too). One fine morning her account is no longer active and she is not able to login. She first thought that she is doing something wrong with open id and then later I realized that my rep went down (as she voted on some my answers too) and we figured out that her account got deleted. on what basis an account will be deleted here on SO???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess would be that since this is a colleague, its possible SO was picking up both your activity and hers as coming from the same location. Therefore, if there was a high correlation in terms of voting on each other's activity, perhaps the [vote fraud detection](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/) algorithm determined the accounts to be the same person and deleted one. I don't know for certain if the fraud detection goes this far, but I wouldn't be surprised if it does. Either way, the next step is to contact the SO team at team@stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Thanks guys. May be that is the reason. I will warn other colleagues not to use SO so that only will represent the team or we will use only one account per IP or Never vote a colleagues answer/upvote a question even if its relevant.

Answer (score 2):

If a specific account has shown no activity for four months and the rep is < 100, the account is **unregistered**. See [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/) for more.

If your colleague's account does not fall into this category she should contact team@stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Hmm. Just checked with her, she said she used it on Friday and by Monday her account got deleted, Anyhow she is not that interested(rather say lost interest) in coming again

Comment: @Teja - what was her display name? Does she still show up in the user list?

Comment: @John B, Her name is 'Madhavi P', She said she just recreated account after our discussion here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Timothy has the truth of it. Unfortunately, heavily biased voting between colleagues *will* tend to make one of the accounts appear "suspect". If something was erroneous, the account can *possibly* be recovered.

Comment: Wouldn't a notification be sent to a user prior to an account being torched?  An email sent (assuming one is listed in the profile) or a comment on a post asking the user to notify the Team?  I could see if no email and no posts, but in this case where rep was earned that would not be the case unless the rep came solely from account association.

Comment: @suillman I think the best thing to do is to make it unequivocally clear in your profile that you are a real person. Most puppet accounts are empty, which looks suspicious. For people working in the same office, I would suggest including your City/State/Country in the profile which will help Mods as they review activity.

Comment: That's why I always hijack a new random machine on the internet for each of my sockpuppets.  One can never be _too_ careful...