# Why did I just lose 50 reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

I suddenly lost 50 reputation points. My display name is 'Teja Kantamneni'. What happened? The activity is not showing any '-ve' or 'red'..

**EDIT:** It's on SO, not on meta.

Comment: Someone probably cast "septum-sempra" on your account, dealing you 50 rep damage.

Comment: Even I lost 50 points right now. Well, my friends did upvoted me but it was there decision. I did not asked them as a favor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your account appears to have undergone a routine recalc. Nothing to be alarmed of. This may have been triggered by suspicious voting, or any number of other things.

With regards to voting for coworkers, or having coworkers vote for you, I'd suggest not doing this. If you find this is easier than inter-office communication, just make sure your coworkers provide a descriptive profile to give legitimacy to them being a real person. Most puppet-accounts tend to be empty.

Moderators understand that two people in the same office may share the same IP. For this reason, help us out by making it clear you are two legitimate users to avoid any confusion. And try not to upvote in excess one another to avoid upsetting the machines :)

Another thing you may consider is encouraging co-workers to mention their city/state where the office is located in their profile. To go the extra-mile, mention the company name to really make it clear that you use Stack Overflow in an office environment with others.

Comment: Ok, so it means I lost my rep??

Comment: Your recalc removed rep that didn't belong. It didn't rob you of anything. It's like a cashier finding out she gave you $10 too much in your change and then asking for the extra $10 back.

Comment: In some cases it can go the other way around. Such as the cashier finding out that she only gave you $10 change when you were suppose to get $40

Comment: I wouldn't give it back... I'd run, as far as the $10 take me

Comment: @Chacha102: Correct. In fact, I just did a rep-recalc for somebody and witnessed them come out on top :)

Comment: @Downvoter - And what about the other $20?  /pedantic

Comment: It was me (the recalc, not the $20). See below.

Comment: @Marc Oooo! Can I have the $20?

Answer (score 7):

Hands up - that was me. I was looking into what happened in your [*previous* question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41520/when-will-a-user-get-deleted-in-so), and instead of hitting "history", I hit "recalc" (they are very close together). This triggered the "cashier" scenario Jonathan described.

So the click on "recalc" was me - but the new value is just routine activity. Here, I'll recalc myself: I "lost" 15 points (in reality, I never *had* those 15 points).

Comment: Hey, if you aren't busy, could you please recalc the rep on my 2 accounts you have access to?

Comment: No no, me first!

Comment: You've just described the economic problems of the US in your last sentence

Comment: @GMan - is that an actual request?

Comment: Can you do me too? I don't think I've ever been recalced. And I just dropped off of page 3, so I have nothing to lose now.

Comment: @mmyers - done.

Comment: @Jonathan: Thanks. Less than 400 rep, so not as bad as I thought. :)

Comment: @Marc: Naw, I was just picking on the inevitable "hey, recalc me!" wave, which turned out to be smaller than I thought. :p

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to the [other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41520/when-will-a-user-get-deleted-in-so) you just asked.

Stack Overflow probably detected anomalies in the vote pattern between your account and the account you said got deleted. It probably thought that the account that got deleted was a sock puppet account, so it deleted that, and cancelled the upvotes that account gave you. I'm guessing that deleted account upvoted you 5 times, so you've lost 5x10 = 50 reputation.

For more details, you'll need to e-mail team@stackoverflow.com. If I were you, I'd send a single e-mail with this question and the other one. We're all just guessing at the cause, they can actually tell you what happened.

Comment: That happened a few weeks back, today just now I lost again, Is there any place I can see those details,

Comment: *"Is there any place I can see those details"* No. That high moderator and team mojo. No amount of rep brings those details into view.