# 50 Reputation lost

Tags: discussion, reputation, lost-reputation

I associated my account with another yahoo account, and after that I lost 50 reputation.
Why is it so?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/reputation say anything useful?

Comment: Nope. It isn't of much help.

Comment: Possibly related: [Why did I just lose 50 reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41527/why-did-i-just-lose-50-reputation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reputation here doesn't get affected by association of your external accounts. It does get affected by your linking of your Stack Exchange network accounts. For example, I see you have >200 rep on Stack Overflow, and <100 rep here on Meta Stack Overflow. Try this:

- go to your MSO profile
- click the accounts tab
- disassociate your SO account
- reassociate your SO account
- get a one-time +100 rep bonus on MSO

You should be able to do the same thing on the Programmers SE beta. Please try that, and update your question if you don't get the expected behavior.

Comment: @Reality, good, I'm glad that worked. As for your 50 rep, did you previously have SE accounts with both Yahoo! accounts?

Comment: Yep. I had already associated my SO account with Yahoo! one, but i use my Open-Id to login. Is this beacuse I re-associated it?

Comment: @Reality, I'm not a mod/admin so I can't confirm, but I would guess that you accidentally voted for some of your SO questions while using the other account or had a routine recalc done when the accounts were merged. I'll keep poking around.

Comment: "accidentally", heh.

Comment: Eh, OP came here to Meta to ask, that alone is worth the benefit of the doubt.